# How to execute selenium test cases on multiple node on IE11 browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-grid, selenium-iedriver

I am facing an issue like when try to execute selenium test case on two separate nodes on IE11 browser then it gets to hang on both node after open login page on IE browser.

```
node configuration is:
java -jar D:\SeleniumServer\selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role node  -hub http://192.***.***.**:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,javascriptEnabled=true,version=50,platform=WINDOWS -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=d:\SeleniumServer\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=d:\SeleniumServer\BrowserDrivers\IEDriverServer.exe -browser "browserName=internet explorer, javascriptEnabled=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS"
```

Note: for chrome its working fine,
what kind of configuration required to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

When I used IEDriverServer 64 bit version, execution is very slow, so I have changed it to 32bit version which is worked fine for me. Try this once. And also, check whether your application is working in IE browser when you try to access it manually.